# Wifi module stops connect to any access points

Tags: wireless, dell

After an update wifi stops connecting to any network (excluding router at work). It just tries to connect and after that asks for the password again and again.

I tried to reinstall the driver but that doesn't help.

```
12:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)
Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS \n \l
```

It's strange because this is a Dell Vostro 1440 which is in certified Ubuntu laptop list.

Answer (score 0):

There problems with broadcom chipset and wpa-supplicant driver. I buy external wifi module on realtek chipset and all works fine.